# adding / to internet address causes asp:Image not loading

Tags: html, asp.net, image, path

My code:

`<asp:Image runat="server" alt="not loaded" ImageUrl="picture.png" />`

On site address

> example.com/tabid/233/Default.aspx

everything works, but on address ("/" added)

> example.com/tabid/233/Default.aspx/

my page looks like before but picture is not loaded. Does somebody can explain it to me and give an adive what to do to have picture always loaded?

Comment: Debug in firebug, try to change image path in firebug and see if your url is correct. Normally we put image in a folder, not in root, don't we?

Answer (score 0):

If image in root u can map image like this.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" alt="not loaded" ImageUrl="~/picture.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Default.aspx is your page and Default.aspx/ references to a folder. If you want to use / at the and, you can try routing or apply rewrite rules.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change the "ImageUrl" attribute in the Image tag to something like...

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/picture.png" />
```

The extra "/" has the browser looking a folder deeper than it should be for the image.